# Custom Mysqli function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a custom function that I use to make it easier for me in a project I work with.
But now it won't work properly, so I hope that someone here can help me out.
The code looks like the following:

```
function custom_new_offer($conns,$adminOfferName,$adminOfferNeed,$adminOfferAmount) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO items_offer (offer_name, offer_need, offer_amount) VALUES ('$adminOfferName', '$adminOfferNeed','$adminOfferAmount')";
mysqli_query($sql) or die ("Failed query".mysqli_error($conns));
}
```

and the query looks like:

```
$sql = custom_new_offer($conn,"plank","plank","2");
```

But it just returns the "Failed query" error message and not the `mysqli_error` that I wanted it to.

Comment: Has anything changed lately with your server. Ie upgraded php version, changed mysql users etc?

Comment: Hello! No, i plan to upgrade the php version but haven't done it yet. Everything is still the same :)

Comment: Small thing. You have `$conns` in the function `$conn` for the `$sql`, sure this is not it, just thought I'd point it out. Have you ensured the mysql connection is working as suggested by Jelle's answer (since been removed), maybe create a quick function to test and do a select or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysqli connection is not used in your query. Add the $conns to the mysqli_query() command

```
mysqli_query($conns, $sql)
```

Comment: Ofcourse i have an connection to the database, $conns is the mysqli_connect variable. Thanks :)

Comment: Considering he is getting no output for mysqli_error(), I believe that could very well be the answer. $conn is not an active DB connection.

Comment: @CornexHay change your $sql to something trivial like `select 1 as test` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Rikesh, i just solved it and saw you answer it also. But this was the problem, still used to mysql haha :( .. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  function custom_new_offer($conns,$adminOfferName,$adminOfferNeed,$adminOfferAmount) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO items_offer (offer_name, offer_need, offer_amount) VALUES ('$adminOfferName', '$adminOfferNeed','$adminOfferAmount')";

   mysqli_query($conns,$sql);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following may work better instead of the function you currently use as it would check that the connection was created first before using `mysqli_query`.  You should however consider using prepared statements instead of building the query in a string though.

```
function custom_new_offer($conns, $adminOfferName, $adminOfferNeed, $adminOfferAmount) {
    if (!$conns) {
        die("Connect Error (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO items_offer (offer_name, offer_need, offer_amount)"
              ."VALUES ('$adminOfferName', '$adminOfferNeed', '$adminOfferAmount')";
        mysqli_query($conns, $sql) or die ("Failed query".mysqli_error($conns));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know, this was just the start of it :p but thanks anyway